# Inner Join with 2 arrays using JOLT. I want to do a join with two arrays that the objects have the same id.(example below)

Tags: arrays, json, join, inner-join, jolt

I want to do a join with two arrays that the objects have the same id.(example below)

```json
{
  "body": {
    "array1": [
      {
        "id": "13910",
        "name": "A"
      }
    ],
    "array2": [
      {
        "id": "13910",
        "name": "B"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I tried this Jolt spec but my output is "null"

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "body": {
        "array1": {
          "*": {
            "id": {
              "@(2,body.array2[&1].id)": {
                "*": "result[&3].&1.&"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the key is to use the id as the key to select all the objects in both arrays, I believe it is an inner join, right?

I'm accepting suggestions

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. What you want to get seems unclear to me. Can you please add the expected output as well ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is the expected output in this case but assuming its this:

```
{
  "result" : [ {
    "id" : "13910",
    "name" : [ "A", "B" ]
  } ]
}
```

You can try the following spec:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "body": {
        "array1": {
          "*": {
            "id": {
              "@(3,array2[&1].id)": {
                "@": "result[&3].&1",
                "@(2,name)": "result[&3].name",
                "@(4,array2[&2].name)": "result[&3].name"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

If you have many fields to merge and you want to avoid listing them, you can use something more generic but you have to do it in two transformation

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "body": {
        "array1": {
          "*": {
            "id": {
              "@(3,array2[&1].id)": {
                "@(2,)": "result",
                "@(4,array2[&2])": "result"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "result": {
        "0": {
          "id": "result[#].id",
          "*": "result[#].&"
        },
        "*": {
          "id": null,
          "*": "result[#].&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```